# How to display bandwidth only in iperf?

Tags: awk, grep

I want to know how to display only the bandwidth value in iperf. I use grep but it displays the entire row like this :

```
iperf -c 10.0.0.1 -i 1 -t 100 | grep -i --color Mbit/sec
```

the result is

```
[3] 0.0 - 1.0 sec 128 Kbytes 1.05 Mbits/sec
[3] 1.0 - 2.0 sec 128 Kbytes 11.5 Mbits/sec
[3] 2.0 - 3.0 sec 128 Kbytes 31.5 Mbits/sec
```

That I want is

```
1.05
11.5
31.5
```

I heard about awk but I don't know how to use in this problem. Could anyone tell how to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` is sufficient for this.  You can say:

```
iperf -c 10.0.0.1 -i 1 -t 100 | grep -Po '[0-9.]*(?= Mbits/sec)'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
iperf -c 10.0.0.1 -i 1 -t 100 | grep -i --color Mbit/sec | sed -u -n "s/^.*Kbytes \([0-9.,]\{1,\}\) Mbit.*$/\1/p"
```

you should use `sed -n -u` if this is a stream input, if file copy the `-u` could be removed

grep could be also removed including a `"/pattern/ !"` before the `"s/"` to remove the unwanted line (i have no acces to iperf here, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`, you can do this

```
iperf -c 10.0.0.1 -i 1 -t 100 | awk '/Mbits\/sec/ {print $8}'
1.05
11.5
31.5
```